# Returning objects with multiple types in a RESTful way

Tags: rest, mobile

I'm currently designing an API to handle requests from mobile clients. To achieve some degree of decoupling between backend and client I would like to define the webservices in a RESTful way. The challenge that I am facing is returning multiple objects with different types for a single call.

Lets say we have the following Model:

- *Harbour* ... Top level entry
- *Boat shed* ... Assigned to a specific harbour (0..n)
- *Boat* ... Assigned to a specific boat shed (0..n), or directly to a harbour (0..n)

As far as i understand REST, if I now want to display all the boats and sheds in the harbour I would send two requests:

`/harbours/{harbour_id}/boats` Returning a list of all boats. Boats in a shed would contain an id linking to the shed they are in

`/harbours/{harbour_id}/sheds` Returning a list of all sheds

As I want to use the web service in a mobile scenario, it would be ideal to combine these two calls into one. This could then either return the list of boats with the shed object nested within, or both object types side by side:

```
/harbours/22/boats

[
   {
      "id":1,
      "boatName":"Mary",
      "boatShed":{
         "id":1,
         "shedName":"Dock 1",
         "capacity":55
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "boatName":"Jane",
      "boatShed":{
         "id":1,
         "shedName":"Dock 1",
         "capacity":55
      }
   }
]
```

or

```
/harbours/22/boats

{
   "boats":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "boatName":"Mary",
         "boatShedId":1
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "boatName":"Jane",
         "boatShedId":1
      }
   ],
   "sheds":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "shedName":"Dock 1",
         "capacity":55
      }
   ]
}
```

My question now is, which of these ways is closer to the idea behind REST, or is it not RESTful at all?

Comment: The first option is more RESTful. The secound returns sheds if you ask for boats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tarken mentioned `/boats` request should not return sheds in the top level (since the url assumes you're asking for collection of resource `Boat`)

If you have relations defined as follows

```
Harbour:
    boats: Boat[]
    sheds: Shed[]

Shed:
    boats: Boat[]

Boat:
    harbour: Harbour
    shed: Shed
```

`/harbours/ID` then returns a `Harbour` representation with `boats` and `sheds` relation set.

```
{
  boats: 
  [
    { Boat },
    { Boat },
    ..
  ],
  sheds: 
  [
    { Shed },
    { Shed },
    ..
  ],
  ...
}
```

Nothing is against restful principles here - the url uniquely identifies a resource and resource representation can be anything, with links to other resources as well.

Comment: So it is not a problem, if we have a nested model here?

Comment: So what would be returned if I would ask for /harbours ? As it is a mobile scenario, it would be good to request just as much as needed. If I already return all the boats and sheds there I would already transmit quite a bit of data, that I probably don't need.

Comment: @Paul If api entities have rich representation (like harobour linking to sheds and boats) it's a good idea to add field selectors support and specifiy which fields you need upon a query.
So you could do something like `/harbours?_fields=id,name` to exclude sheds and boats from query. That way you're not only reducing the size of transmitted data but also eliminating extra db calls.

Comment: Check out linkedin implementation: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/field-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Harbour` model which contains both `Boat Shed` and `Boat` information. If i am implementing the service in Java, then i would have done something like this :

```
class Boat{
...
}

class BoatShed{
...
}

class Harbour{
List<Boat> boats;
List<BoatShed> boatSheds;
...
}
```

You can create an API like `/api/harbours/{harbourId}`.

As per your question you want to display all the boats and sheds in the `harbour`, say `id=1234`, you can make a request like this :

`GET /api/harbours/1234`

This will return list of `Boats` and list of `Boat Sheds` like this:

```
{
"boats":[
  {
     "id":1,
     "boatName":"Mary",
     "boatShedId":1
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "boatName":"Mary2",
     "boatShedId":2
  }
],
"sheds":[
  {
     "id":1,
     "shedName":"Dock 1",
     "capacity":55
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "shedName":"Dock 2",
     "capacity":50
  }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT**
As you want to get `boats` and `Sheds` side by side by sending one request, the `api/hourbours/{id}` looks good according to `REST API` design principles.

Getting all `sheds` while requesting for `boats` is not in accordance with ideal REST API design, but if you want to achieve the same you can d the following.

If you want that way, then `first one` `/api//harbours/{id}/boats` looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joshi, unfortunately that doesn't answer my question. I wanted to know how you would do it in a proper REST style. It wasn't clear to me whether a model like the described one is to be returned side by side or nested when following REST.

Comment: Same question here as for the one of max_i: As I'm in a mobile scenario I want to keep my transmitted data minimal. So when requesting for /harbours I don't want to get a list of all the harbours and boats. That results in the problem that /harbours and /harbours/{id} would return different models.

Comment: yeah true. So as i have mentioned you can go with the first approach.